# PowerShell - Convert Ticks to Time

Tags: powershell

Converting dates/times into ticks using the PowerShell Get-Date applet is simple.  However, how do you do the opposite operation; converting the ticks back into a date and time?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
[DateTime]10000000000
Monday, January 01, 0001 12:16:40 AM
```

Just cast the number into a `DateTime`.  The `DateTime` single-parameter constructor takes a `long` as number of ticks.

Comment: I suspected that it was something simple.  This is what happens when you try to learn PowerShell, .NET, and Active Directory at the same time..

Comment: Welcome to the stack!  PowerShell does take a little getting used to, but I really think that it brings a lot of flexibility and strength to Windows that wasn't there before unless you wanted to deal with some sort of Unix toolset like MKSToolkit.

Answer (score 5):

Note that you can use the `Get-Date` cmdlet to also do the reverse operation:

```
PS> Get-Date 634141193308872671

Mittwoch, 7. Juli 2010 17:08:50
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the New-Object cmdlet:

```
PS > get-date

Friday, July 09, 2010 12:01:42 AM


PS > (get-date).ticks
634142305097923801

PS > New-Object System.DateTime 634142305097923801

Friday, July 09, 2010 12:01:49 AM
```