# Comparing TICKS time in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to compare two TICKS times, and i need the comparisons to be a little less precise and consider DateTime objects equal even if they were a few milliseconds apart (half minute tops) by removing any excess milliseconds and ticks from their DateTime objects ([following jacubs guide](https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/02/18/pstip-comparing-datetime-with-a-given-precision/)).

problem is that my first ticks value ($date1) is generate from a performance counter, and i cannot convert him back to Date time again (Get-Date -Date ($date1)), getting the following error message:

> Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'.  Cannot convert value
>   "636763462457113590" to type "System.DateTime". Error:  "String was
>   not recognized as a valid dateTime"

This is my script:

```
$date1 = (Get-Counter -Counter '\TimeCheck\TIME').CounterSamples[0] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty RawValue
    Get-Date $date1
    Get-Date -Date ($date1) -Millisecond 0  | Select -ExpandProperty Ticks

    $date2 = Get-Date
    $date2.Ticks
    Get-Date -Date ($date2) -Millisecond 0  | Select -ExpandProperty Ticks

    $date1 -eq $date2
```

The only method this command works for me is if i wrote the TICKS time itself:

```
PS C:> Get-Date -Date 636763462457113590
Sunday, October 28, 2018 5:57:25 PM
```

What i'm doing wrong? even using out-string isn't working.

Comment: this looks like it covers the idea ... PowerShell - Convert Ticks to Time - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140576/powershell-convert-ticks-to-time

Comment: Thanks but not so helping, I'm already know how to convert from TICKS back to date time.. but my problem is how to accomplish that while using a variable (Get-Date -Date ($date1))

Comment: i don't think you read all the way thru the post. [*grin*] `[datetime]$Ticks` will give you a datetime object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like $date1  in "Get-Date -Date ($date1)" is not numeric (based on error)
try Get-Date -Date ([int64]$date1) or  [datetime][int64]$date1

Comment: are you still getting error after forced type conversion?

Comment: I'm currently cannot access my lab, I will update when ii will be available.. but can you please explain to me what ([int64]$date1) is doing? I'm guessing converting to integer in 64 base?

Answer (score 0):

this will convert from a tick count to a datetime object ...

```
$Ticks = 636763462457113590
$TimeFromTicks = [datetime]$Ticks

$TimeFromTicks
```

output = `2018 October 28, Sunday 5:57:25 PM`